# Launch Firefox OS app when notification is tapped

Tags: javascript, notifications, firefox-os

I have been unsuccessfully trying to implement notification click (tap) handlers for my Firefox OS app.

API documentation on the Notification object is here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

In my app, I have an function that will launch the phone's browser when a notification is tapped and navigate to a URL:

```
notification.onclick = function(){
   var navURL = new MozActivity(
   {
       name: "view",
       data: {
           type: "url",
           url: "https://google.com"
       }
    });

    console.log("Notification tapped");
};
```

When the user is viewing the app and taps a notification, my app **will** launch the browser and navigate to Google's homepage accordingly.

However, if my app is running in the background, nothing happens when the notification is tapped.  The  console will still print the "Notification tapped" message (so apparently the event handler is called), but the browser **does not** launch.  Go back into the app and everything works fine again.

Is there a way to get the browser to launch even when my app is in the background?

**EDIT: ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION**

Is it possible to bring my app back up into the foreground when the notification is tapped?

Comment: Try to set a onsuccess and onerror callback to your activity, just to see what happens

Comment: Hmmm...I did add the callbacks to my MozActivity; when the app is running in the foreground, the onsuccess callback is used.  When the app is running in the background, the onerror callback is used.  Hmmm...is there a way to bring an app to the foreground?

Comment: [try this](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram/issues/365), basically is just

`window.mozApps.getSelf().onsuccess = function() {
      this.result.launch();
    };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
notification.onclick = function(){
    var navURL = new MozActivity(
   {
       name: "view",
       data: {
           type: "url",
           url: "https://google.com"
       }
   });
   navUrl.onsuccess = function () {
       // fired if appication is running foreground
   }
   navUrl.onerror = function () {
       // fired if application is running background
       navigator.mozApps.getSelf().onsuccess = function (){
           this.result.launch();
       }
   }
};
```

As already said before this should work

Comment: Great; thanks!  I looked up the API docs, it's actually the `window.navigator.mozApps` object; not the `window.mozApps` object.  So `navigator.mozApps.getSelf().onsuccess` got the job done.

Comment: I know this is old thread, I'm also trying something similar. Difference is, trying share activity (share on fb/whatsapp), where I can share custom url on social n/w. Can you please assist.. I've tried different ways, but I'm facing issue shared on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60809383/how-to-share-link-on-facebook-from-own-application-kai-os-feature-phone